# Reversing list in place in python with O(1) extra memory

Tags: python

I came across the problem of reversing a list in place in python with O(1) extra memory.

```
def reverseString(self, s: List[str]) -> None:
    s[:] = s[::-1]
```

But I was guessing even if this is O(1)?
I just tried this:

```
>>> s = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> id(s)
2626086228672
>>> id(s[::-1])
2626086761664
```

So, I just realize, even doing `s[::-1]` will create a new instance and hence cannot be in-place or have O(1) space complexity. In fact any solution with slicing operation wont be O(1), right?

**Q1.** Am I right with these?

A side question: I tried following:

```
>>> id(s[2:])
2626086761664
```

**Q2.** Why `id(s[2:])` is same as `id(s[::-1])`?

Comment: For **Q1**, I think you are right. For **Q2**, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291474/pointers-all-the-same-in-list-comprehension-even-though-they-shouldnt/72291518#72291518

Comment: O() notation is used for computation time.  Yes, every slicing operation creates a new object.

Comment: Q2: [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id): *Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.*

Comment: You are right about the complexity, but your question body talks about O(1) time complexity and the title asks about O(1) memory. You *can* reverse a list in constant space, but it’s not clear if that’s what you are asking.

Comment: [Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hrx8W9141)

Comment: @Mark sorry that "time" in question body was a typo.